# Return other View without Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have two controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Menus()
{
    // Build view model and display Menus view
}

public ActionResult MenuCommand(string commandArg)
{
    // Perform the specified action

    // Now return new Menus views
    return Menus();
}
```

The idea that is, after my `MenuCommand` action is finished, it defers back to the original handler for this page.

But in the code above, I get the following error after my `MenuCommand()` action executes.

> The view 'MenuCommand' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

I believe I can resolve this using `RedirectToAction("Menus")` instead. However, a redirect is inefficient. It returns the redirect back to the browser, and the browser must then make a second request. Why is this necessary? Can't I simply return the results of a different action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the concerns I have in my question are valid. A redirect is inefficient.

However, without the redirect, the browser still thinks I'm viewing the "MenuCommand" URL. This can cause problems. For example, any links will be relative to the URL the browser considers the current page. It's better to inform the browser of the correct URL that is currently being displayed.

Therefore, I think the best practice is to use `RedirectToAction()` despite its inefficiencies.